# Emacs sloppy focus no longer working - 2 second delay on changing focus

Tags: emacs, focus

I have the following set in my init.el

```
(setq focus-follows-mouse 1)
(setq mouse-autoselect-window 1)
```

This is intended, and was previously working, to cause emacs to automatically switch focus to the window where my mouse was hovered over, instantly.
However, there is now a ~2 second delay in switching.

Any ideas what might be causing this, with no other notable changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for `mouse-autoselect-window`:

> A positive number means delay autoselection by that many seconds: a window is autoselected only after the mouse has remained in that window for the duration of the delay.

So the effect of `(setq mouse-autoselect-window 1)` would be to delay one second before selecting the window the mouse was over.  This sounds sort of like what you are seeing.

I'm not sure if this behaviour has changed recently, but FWIW, I'm using emacs 23.1.1.

To get instantaneous window selection, use `(setq mouse-autoselect-window t)`.

Comment: Thank you! I read somewhere that I should change my ts and nils to 1s and 0s respectively - so that caused it. Cheers again :)